# Azure DevOps Release error "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Pipelines.PipelineValidationException (type ReleaseManagementHandledException)"

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Azure DevOps Release was working fine, and no changes were made on the pipeline, but suddenly the release start throwing the following error:

[image]

Comment: Check the Azure Key Vault  for ConnectedServiceName reference with the GUID mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

The exception clearly describes problem
Check if service connection still exists and check the permissions.
[image]